# how to display position based image for following code?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-gridview

I have the following code. When I click on an image in grid view that particular image should display in another activity. How can I do that?

This is my Activity class::

```
public class ProductsActivity extends Activity {
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.grid_view);

    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this));
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
        {
            // this 'mActivity' parameter is Activity object, you can send the current activity.
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MobileDisplayActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("positionId",position);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

How do I can change my adapter class to achieve my requirement. Ithink the problem is in `getView()`.

```
this is my adapter class:
    private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MyAdapter(Context context)
    {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        items.add(new Item("Image 1", R.drawable.ic_image4));
        items.add(new Item("Image 2", R.drawable.ic_image5));
        items.add(new Item("Image 3", R.drawable.ic_image4));
        items.add(new Item("Image 4", R.drawable.ic_image5));
        items.add(new Item("Image 5", R.drawable.ic_image4));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i)
    {
        return items.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i)
    {
        return items.get(i).drawableId;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
    {
        View v = view;
        ImageView picture;
        TextView name;

        if(v == null)
        {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_grid, viewGroup, false);
            v.setTag(R.id.picture, v.findViewById(R.id.picture));
            v.setTag(R.id.text, v.findViewById(R.id.text));
        }

        picture = (ImageView)v.getTag(R.id.picture);
        name = (TextView)v.getTag(R.id.text);

        Item item = (Item)getItem(i);

        picture.setImageResource(item.drawableId);
        name.setText(item.name);

        return v;
    }

    private class Item
    {
        final String name;
        final int drawableId;

        Item(String name, int drawableId)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.drawableId = drawableId;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: http://androidbite.blogspot.in/2012/09/android-custom-gallery-application.html

Comment: thank you sir for your kind replay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than sending the position of the item to the next activity, you could send the id or your drawables (which is also integer).

Do it this way

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
{
    // this 'mActivity' parameter is Activity object, you can send the current activity.
    int imageId = ((Item) parent.getItemAtPosition(position)).drawableId;
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MobileDisplayActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("imageId", imageId);
    startActivity(i);
 }
```

In the `MobileDisplayActivity` activity simple do this

```
int imageId = getIntent().getIntExtra("imageId", 0);
if(imageId > 0)
    imageView.setBackgroundResource(imageId);
else
    // something went wrong
```

**NOTE:** Make `Item` class public static or define it independently.

Comment: @brahmyadigopula: What do you mean by *exact image*?

Comment: i mean positioned image in gridView @Rohit

Comment: its even not showing anything after clicking on image except blank layout

Comment: its okay sir..i sort out the problem...its all about manifest file..i forget to put intent inflater for the MobileDisplayActivity class...thanks for your kind replay

Answer (score 1):

You should put in the intent the drawable id like in the code below:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    int drawableId = ((Item) parent.getItemAtPosition(position)).drawableId;
    Intent intent = new Intent(ProductsActivity.this, MobileDisplayActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("DRAWABLE_ID", drawableId); 
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Also you should make the Item class public static in order to have access to it from activity. drawableId should be public (or you could create a getter for this field).

Comment: its working but  not displaying the image..its just displaying blank page

Comment: The problem seems to be in MobileDisplayActivity

Comment: i sort out the problem sir...the problem  is in intent filter adding in manifest file.thanks for your kind replay